# Conditional and past

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it correct to say:

> "If someone was born in the 90s, he's now over 15."

If yes what kind of conditional is it?

Comment: It is a **set-identifying inferential conditional**, and entirely OK. Like many, many English conditionals it does not conform to any of the 'canonical' types. "1st, 2nd, 3rd conditional" are not actual linguistic categories but teaching devices employed to familiarize students with a handful of common forms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phrase is right, bur most correctly you might use "would be". Then:

### If someone was born in the 90s, he would be now over 15.

The kind of conditional is the "Sencond conditional" beacuse is a hypothetical situation. It's formed with "if+past simple  +  would/could/might+verb".

Comment: 1) Your rewrite is acceptable, but it is not "more correct" than the original. It's just different.  2) Your rewrite is not what is usually taught as "2nd conditional", which calls for "If someone *were* born" to express an unreal condition. Not that it matters, since "2nd conditional" doesn't have any actual linguistic meaning.

Comment: @StoneyB : what do you mean by `"2nd conditional" doesn't have any actual linguistic meaning.`

Comment: @Vadi Such statement probably was meant for the context given in your sentence.

Comment: @Vadi "1st, 2nd, 3rd conditional" are terms used by teachers to introduce students to conditional constructions. They only name a fraction of all conditionals, and the ones they name are just forms, which don't always mean what the teachers tell you they mean.